# Only show shares the logged in user has permissions for

Tags: samba

I am using Samba for quite some time now and I am wondering if there is a solution to the following:

I have multiple Shares for different users.
Is there a way to show only the shares the logged in user has permissions for??

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Use the parameter [`access based share enum`](https://www.samba.org/samba/docs/man/manpages-3/smb.conf.5.html#idp58042160). From what I understand, that should be what you are after.

Answer (score -1):

You have not specified the permissions you are using, or if the users are in groups or individuals.  Take a look at the following:

1. Permissions.  Users should be restricted to only the folders they need.  Not even the entire share, but the top level folder they need.  And you can limit access to subfolders if you need to.
2. In the samba config file (smb.conf) have you set the `browsable` parameter, in the [homes] section? It should read `browsable = no`.  This should achieve what you want.
3. I take it you have set the read/write permissions to each share in smb.conf.

According to the Samba docs, the `read list` and `write list` parameters override all other access configurations, so make sure those lists have only the necessary users.  [www.samba.org/samba/docs/](http://www.samba.org/samba/docs/)